# "No Action Needed" for a deleted answer

Tags: support, review-queues

Here is the screenshot of the answer from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339632/page-not-found-on-wordpress-installation)

[image: 1]

I don't know why I saw it in my queue. After I took "No Action Needed", my review was locked.

I have nothing to do with the answer (edit, flag, vote up, vote down, leave a comment....). But......why locking?

Another case: If the answer exists, it has a downvoting, it has 2 comments for why it got the downvoting, what can I do when I see it in the queue? Cannot I leave with "No Action Needed" even if someone'd done it (edit if possible, comment for something...)?

Comment: No, you can skip it. "No Action Needed" suggests to the system that you think the answer is fine when it is not.

Comment: "No Action Needed" Is not saying that what has already been done is enough, but suggesting that the post in question is fine.

Comment: @Bugs You shouldn't be skipping answers that aren't answers either.  You should be flagging them.  If you can't tell if the post is an answer or not, then sure, but if you can't tell for something this clear then you're probably not ready to be reviewing at all.

Comment: @Servy sorry yes you shouldn't and I wouldn't have skipped this as it's clearly NAA. I was suggesting to the OP that they have the opportunity to skip rather than suggesting _No Action Needed_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That answer isn't an answer.  It merits a downvote, and you should be flagging and/or voting to delete it as not an answer, because it's not an answer.  A comment would be appropriate if there weren't already more than one, since there is, upvoting one of the existing comments would also be appropriate.

The answer doesn't "need no action".  It needs *deletion*, because it's not an answer.

You failed to identify a non-answer meriting deletion as having any issues, and as a result, you've been given a break from reviewing.  Hopefully when you go back you'll be more mindful of problematic answers.

Comment: Thanks! If it's a deleted answer, why does it still need an action?

Comment: @TânNguyễn From the review queue it won't appear as deleted at all.  It's an audit, to verify that you'll perform the correct action for the hypothetical situation presented.  You didn't.

Comment: @Servy While that is technically correct, it is not intuitive as far as I'm concerned, at least not until one gets bitten some times. A number of times I also stumbled across some weird case of answer during review, followed the link to see the actual post to get an impression in context, saw that it was already deleted, thought "ah, ok, no action needed *anymore*", clicked that button and got chastised. Probably "No action needed" should be renamed "Answer is OK" or something similar, that would be more intuitive, I would not press that button by mistake in the situation above.

Comment: I haven't thought `upvoting one of the existing comments` is an action before. I will keep in mind it. Many thanks!

Comment: @mkl You'll have had to have made the same mistake *several times* in order to actually get review banned.  And note that the button used to read "looks okay" but when it did people would refuse to click it when an answer wasn't a good answer but wasn't bad enough to merit deletion from the queue.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Note that it's the least helpful of all of the options listed.  You're 100% doing something wrong by not flagging a post like that when you see it, that's simply something else you could *also* do in such a situation.

Comment: @Servy by *chastised* I only meant verbally, not a *ban* (ok, I think once it even triggered a ban, but that was not on my mind when I wrote the comment above)... Oh well, is there something clearly between "No action needed" and "looks okay" so it is intuitively interpreted correctly by everyone? I have to admit I doubt that.

Comment: @mkl Well most of the reviewing system is not fully intuitive, there is a lot of guidance on meta that is pretty much crucial if you're to succeed in understanding the finer nuances of each review queue. Succeeding at reviewing goes hand in hand with your willingness to go look it up on meta first, in my experience.